# Directx11 setting device priority

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to give priority to one my post processing applications. The idea is that even when the underlying application has low frame-rate I should be able present images at the refresh rate via prioritizing my post process application.

I have tried two things.

1. Using `IDXGIDevice::SetGPUThreadPriority`, however this didnt helped. Giving values between -7,7 did nothing.
2. Using a method called `D3DKMTSetProcessSchedulingPriorityClass` in GDI32 library helped me to achieve what I was looking for in desktop devices, but this has one problem it doesnt work on notebooks. It returns `STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` even though the application executed in admin mode.

Do you know anything about this ? Does notebooks have a special case which I should be aware of?

Comment: How do you know that the underlying hardware is able to keep up with the refresh rate at all, regardless of process priority?